# UIImage showing nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm having issues with my project. I'm new to coding. I keep getting the error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb). It seems that the variable "image" is not producing an image and instead producing "nil". the variable "photo" is producing a  name that corresponds with my JPG image name. For some the variable "image" is not able to produce that UIImage and rather is producing nil. Hopefully you can help me.

```
import UIKit

class Photo {

    class func allPhotos() -> [Photo] {
        var photos = [Photo]()
        if let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Photos", withExtension: "plist") {
            if let photosFromPlist = NSArray(contentsOfURL: URL) {
                for dictionary in photosFromPlist {
                    let photo = Photo(dictionary: dictionary as! NSDictionary)
                    photos.append(photo)
                }
            }
        }

        return photos
    }

    var caption: String
    var comment: String
    var image: UIImage

    init(caption: String, comment: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.caption = caption
        self.comment = comment
        self.image = image
    }

    convenience init(dictionary: NSDictionary)  {
        let caption = dictionary["Caption"] as? String
        let comment = dictionary["Comment"] as? String
        let photo = dictionary["Photo"] as? String
        let image = UIImage(named: photo!)?.decompressedImage
        self.init(caption: caption!, comment: comment!, image: image!)
    }

    func heightForComment(font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let rect = NSString(string: comment).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.height)
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that it has to do with the decompression of the image:

import UIKit

extension UIImage {

```
var decompressedImage: UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)
    drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
    let decompressedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return decompressedImage
}
```

}

Comment: @maddy I expect that it's one of SO's suggested tags, and new developers don't necessarily realize that it's not relevant.

Comment: Where are you storing these images?  Have you checked that an image names photo definitely exists with that exact name?

Comment: @Hyperion I have the images bundled in a folder labeled Photos.xcassets . I can see the images in the library with the correct image names

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's these two lines:

```
let image = UIImage(named: photo!)?.decompressedImage
self.init(caption: caption!, comment: comment!, image: image!)
```

The first line assigns a value to `image` but **specifically allows for a nil value**. That's what the `?` implies. Also, in `decompressedImage` (the purpose of which is... unclear) the call to `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` is allowed to return nil.

Then in the second line you use `image!` without checking whether it's nil. It **is** nil, according to your crash, which implies that one of the following is true:

- `photo` doesn't actually contain the name of an image in your app bundle, or
- `photo` has a valid name but the file is somehow corrupt to the point where `UIImage` can't handle it, or
- `decompressedImage` is returning nil, because `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` for some reason.

Comment: I'd like to add another possibility - the OP is only surmising that image is to fault.  If dictionary doesn't contain a key "Photo" then that would also cause the same crash come the UIImage line

Comment: I'd say that the main error here is the force unwrapping of `photo`. By the definition of the variable, it is allowed to take the value `nil` (which might depend on the dictionary as well as the Photo and so on). The following clause `photo!` is then the main source of error in this code, as it goes against the main "optional code convention" that we make use of in Swift.

Comment: @dfri photo! is returning the correct value. I have a feeling it has to do with the .decompressedImage . I need to look into it a little more

Comment: @ajayb I'm speaking about the convention of force-unwrapping optionals here. You define `photo` as `let photo = dictionary["Photo"] as? String`, a definition in essence saying that *"it's ok if `photo` has value `nil`"*. But at the line following, you force-unwrap the value of `photo`, in essence saying *"I know for certain that `photo` will never have the value `nil`, hence I can force-unwrap it at this point"*. If you know for sure that `photo` will never be nil, you should do a force-unwrap at the point of defining `photo`, i.e., `let photo = dictionary["Photo"] as! String`.

Comment: ... but even this is dangerous (although not as bad), and you should consider using `if let` or `guard let` clauses in combination with error handling to allow for correct and expected runtime behaviour of your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things going on here that might go wrong at runtime. So I'll focus on one, and advice you to be careful with force unwrapping (`optionalProperty!`) unless you know your optionals and in which situations it's ok to use force unwrapping. If you don't yet know the latter, you should avoid `!`.

Let's look at this segment of code

```
let image = UIImage(named: photo!)?.decompressedImage
```

As you mention, `photo` is an optional string that *might be nil*. But if we look at the [class reference or UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:), specifically the initialiser `UIImage(named: ...)`, it specifies

```
init?(named name: String)
```

I.e., the parameter `named` should be a string. `nil` is not a string and hence your error.

If we proceed to assume that `photo` actually forcefully unwrapped to a string (path), we have our next problem; *"Value of type UIImage has no member 'decompressedImage'"*. Looking back at the [class reference for `UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:), we can't find this method here.

Anyway, I suggest read up on optionals and optional chaining in swift (`if let`, `guard let`, error handling), e.g.

- [Optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

In your specific case, you need to handle, at the very least, the case where expression `dictionary["Photo"] as? String` returns `nil`.